# Powershell, check that the service is running and if it is not, start it

Tags: windows, powershell

I have created a powershell script that detects if X service is active or not, if not, it starts it. I also wanted to add a parameter in the while to avoid that the script gets stuck and after several attempts (2) it closes the script.

The script works, it starts the service, but it tries to do the or even though the first statement was true. And not the reason why it does not work:

```
$ServiceName = 'MSIREGISTER_MR'
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
$conteo = 0

 

while (($arrService.Status -ne 'Running') -or ($conteo -ne '2'))
{

 

    Start-Service $ServiceName
    write-host $arrService.status
    write-host 'Arrancando el servicio...'
    $conteo = $conteo +1
    Start-Sleep -seconds 5
    $arrService.Refresh()
    if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
    {
        Write-Host 'El servicio esta arrancado'
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Host 'Fallo al arrancar el servicio'
    }

 

}
```

Comment: If you want to test the service then retrieve it in the loop. At the moment you;re retrieving it once then using a static variable `$arrService` throughout

Comment: @Scepticalist: It is the `$arrService.Refresh()` call that keeps the value of `$arrService.Status` current; the real problem is just a logic flaw in the `while` conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why this is happening**

In your script today, you check for the status of the service only once, at the top of the script:

```
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
```

As you can see here, if I try the same using the Xbox Live Game Save Service which is currently stopped on my PC...

```
$service = get-service XblGameSave

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  XblGameSave        Xbox Live Game Save

C:\git\core> $service.Start()
C:\git\core> $service

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  XblGameSave        Xbox Live Game Save
```

I made a variable, I checked it, then I started the service.

When I check, the Xbox Live Game save service, *is actually started*, but my variable doesn't know about it.

However, when I refresh the variable, I can now see the new status.

```
PS> $service.Refresh()

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  XblGameSave        Xbox Live Game Save
```

Refreshing the variable with `.Refresh()` is a VERY weird thing that basically nothing else in PowerShell does other than services.

**What you need to do**

You need to update your code to check within the loop every time, to see if the service is now running or not.

Also, your condition on the loop seems incorrect.

```
while (($arrService.Status -ne 'Running') -or ($conteo -ne '2'))
```

This should run until the service is either running, or `$conteo` is greater than 2 (from your description).  Here's how that should to do that in code.

```
while (($arrService.Status -ne 'Running') -or ($conteo -gt '2'))
```

Comment: It is the `$arrService.Refresh()` call that keeps the value of `$arrService.Status` current; the real problem is just a logic flaw in the `while` conditional.

Comment: That is cool, thanks for the tip.  I always refreshed the variable manually!

Comment: I didn't know about it myself until I saw it in the OP's code :), but it makes sense, akin to the `.Refresh()` method of `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` instances.

Answer (score 0):

There's a **logic flaw in your conditional**; change it to:

```
while ($arrService.Status -ne 'Running' -and $conteo -lt 2) { ...
```

That way, you exit the loop either once the service was started successfully *or* if `$conteo` reaches value `2`, i.e. after the 2nd unsuccessful start attempt.